# PHP not inserting into tables

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having trouble getting a practice signup form to submit data to my database ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body> 

<?php
$name = $email = $password = "";
?>

<form method="post"> 
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="email">
<br><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = fix_input($_POST["name"]);
    $email = fix_input($_POST["email"]);
    $password = fix_input($_POST["password"]);
    mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname") or                 die(mysql_error()); 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ('username','password') VALUES ('$name', md5('$password'))"); 
    Print "You've been signed up successfully"; } 


function fix_input($data)
{   
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: It's no longer considered safe to use `md5` for password storage. The technology dates back to 1996.

Comment: what would you recommend?

Comment: This => http://php.net/password

Comment: Plus, you have multiple issues with your code, by the way, to which no one have yet addressed on the actual syntax errors and what's been given to you so far, won't fix your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ugur's answer, you are mismatching mysqli commands and mysql commands. Here's how to do this in an object oriented fashion:

```
// create mysqli database object
$mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
// store your query in a variable. question marks are filled by variables
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name ('username','password') VALUES (?,?)";
// prepare command uses $sql variable as query
$stmt = mysqli->prepare($sql);
// "ss" means your 2 variables are strings, then you pass your two variables.
$stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,md5($password));
// execute does as it seems, executes the query.
$stmt->execute();
// then print your success message here.
```

Using prepared statements removes the need to sanitize user input, as harmful input is not substituted into the query directly. For more reading:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

There are some good tips for using prepared statements in many different scenarios, as well as towards the bottom, there is an explanation on how prepared statements prevent SQL injection.

Comment: for $stmt->bind_param("ss",$name,md5($password)); I'm getting an error of "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object"

Comment: I edited my answer to include the "new" keyword when creating the "$mysqli" object. Thus, "$mysqli = new mysqli_connect(...);" will fix that error.

Comment: Also, supplied more info on why this approach is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Missing table name

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ......  ('username','password') VALUES ('$name', md5('$password'))");
```

Comment: thanks .... I was too busy looking at the php and overlooking possible sql errors

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` functions, i.e.: `mysqli_connect` and `mysql_query` and you're wrapping your column names in quotes, plus you're missing the table name to insert into.

Try the following, fixed code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$name = fix_input($_POST["name"]);
$email = fix_input($_POST["email"]);
$password = fix_input($_POST["password"]);
mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname") or die(mysql_error()); 
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO `your_table` (`username`,`password`) VALUES ('$name', md5('$password'))"); 
Print "You've been signed up successfully"; }
```

You're also using password storage technology that dates back to 1996. `MD5` is no longer considered safe to use.

I suggest you look into PHP's `password` function: http://php.net/password

And if you're having problems with your `fix_input()` function, you should consider using the [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) function.

then setting up a DB connection while passing a variable to it.

```
$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";

$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
```

and instead of using:

```
$name = fix_input($_POST["name"]);
```

use the following:

```
$name= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
```

and do the same for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have table name in your query! also do not use quotation in your column name :)

you have mixed up mysqli and mysql.
Change

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO ('username','password') VALUES ('$name', md5('$password'))");
```

to

```
mysqli_query("INSERT INTO yoour_table(username',password) VALUES ('$name', md5('$password'))");
```